# Posting a json data to an API method

Tags: php, json, api, post

Can someone check if I included these lines correctly on my code?

```
$headers= array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json');
```

And:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

can you check if this code of mine will work?

```
<?php
$data = array(
             "Name" =>"Your Name Here",
             "ContactNumber" =>"+6390000000",
             "IncidentNature" =>"Disaster",
             "IncidentType" =>"Fire",
             "Facts" =>"Some Facts Here",
             "Location" =>"Location of Incidnet",
             "XCoordinate" =>"145.1523",
             "YCoordinate" =>"89.2542",
            "DateOfIncident" =>"2015-03-23T10:01:00"
         );

 $url_send ="http://my.websiteaddress.com/api/Controller/Action";
 $str_data = json_encode($data);

 function sendPostData($url, $post){
      // I put here the added code
     $headers= array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type:application/json');

     $ch = curl_init($url);

      // I put here the added code
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");  
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);  // Seems like good practice

     return $result;
   }

 echo " " . sendPostData($url_send, $str_data);

?>
```

Comment: Seems fine to me, tested it with no errors. TAKE NOTE, check  the `open_basedir`  if it's on because the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` will  throw a warning if you don't change it in your `php.ini` or you can just use an if statement `if (!ini_get('safe_mode') && !ini_get('open_basedir'))` then if it is set use the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`

Comment: Thanks, I'm not a PHP programmer, that's why I don't know if the 2 line of codes above were placed in the correct sequence inside my code.

Comment: BTW Cedric, have you tried posting a JSON data to an API method built in MVC 4? Actually I'm just trying to help the PHP programmer who will consume my API since he's not familiar with our link...

Comment: the `curl_setopt` is interchangeable, because your are just initializing/setting your parameters to be sent in the said url using the `curl_exec` method.

Comment: Currently using Codeigniter Framework in PHP (an MVC framework also) it's better to curl from model rather than in controller because  it will defeat the purpose of MVC that your getting the datas from model and processes it in the controller. btw MVC 4 is ASP not PHP right?

Comment: Yes, my api is built in ASP.Net MVC 4, and the method is waiting for a posted json data from the consumer of the API.

Comment: As soon as the consumer request to your api and sends the right parameters, the above code will return just as fine as you expect it to be. Are you having problems using it?

Comment: we will try it tomorrow. thanks for checking. :)

Comment: Ok I'll just post the 1st comment as an answer to this question and flag it as answered tomorrow. Thanks.